# About derivation of "regression minimizes empirical risk"

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-learning, derivative

I've been reading Vapnik's Statistical Learning Theory.

In his book, regression is defined as 
$r(x) = \int ydF(y|x)$, where $F(y|x)$ is conditional (cumulative) probability distribution. The risk functional is defined as $R(\alpha) = \int (y - f(x, \alpha))^2dF(y,x)$.

He proved that $f(x,\alpha) = r(x)$ minimizes the $R(\alpha)$:

$R(\alpha) = \int (y - r(x) + r(x) - f(x,\alpha))^2dF(y,x)$
$ = \int (y - r(x))^2dF(y,x) + \int (r(x) - f(x,\alpha))^2dF(x) - 2\int(f(x,\alpha)- r(x)) (y - r(x))dF(y,x)$

Then he claimed that the third integral is zero, which is the part I don't understand, as:

Since by definition $r(x) = \int ydF(y|x) $, the third term can be written as:

$\int(f(x,\alpha)- r(x))\ (y - r(x))dF(y,x) = \int(f(x,\alpha)- r(x))\ [ \int (y - r(x))dF(y|x)]\ dF(x) = 0$

I don't know how he derive the first equal sign there, especially how he managed to transform the derivative joint probability distribution $dF(y,x)$ to $d(F|x)dF(x)$.

In my understanding,

$dF(y,x) = \frac{\partial F(y,x)}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial(F(y,x)}{\partial y}dy = \frac{\partial F(x|y)F(y)}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial(F(y|x)F(x)}{\partial y}dy = F(y)dF(x|y) + F(x)dF(y|x)$.

There's only one derivative in each term here, no product of two derivatives as in $d(F|x)dF(x)$
The only way left possible to make $dF(y|x)dF(x)$ is integral by part. I tried but didn't work out.

Can any one help me on this? Thanks in advance.